# prevent Ubuntu from getting slow without reboot

Tags: reboot

I am implementing some numerical simulations so after some hours or a day, the ubuntu system gets slower so I need to reboot.
Is there any way to keep the system fast without reboot?
It's sometimes annoying to re-open many terminals and the programs as well as to set the directory again after reboot.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  I'm guessing, but I'd guess a program is misbehaving or poorly written (making malloc() [*memory allocate requests*] without subsequently free() [*returning memory*] for use by others or later, causing slowdown), and if you logout & login it may achieve the same result. You didn't give your release or DEsktop, but some will restore open-programs (or you can save a config or selection of configs & have it/one restore [xfce]; though it can't control what the program does after opening it [ie. no `cd` unless you script it])

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be annoying to re-open many terminals. I suggest you install the **CPU Frequency Scaling Indicator** 
(An indicator for monitoring and **switching** CPU frequency scaling) using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```

Once installed (and after you reboot), the app icon should appear in the status bar. You may also make sure that the app is in the list of the startup applications (usually by default). Then you would be able to switch to the

> performance mode

to prevent your system from going into the so called power-save mode and to stay on the performance mode.